# Check if queryable is null before assigning a list

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a working query but most of the space is utilized by just one check to consider if IQueryable is empty or not and based on that the whole query is repeated. Could you please help me come up with an implementation where this check might not be required.

```cs
IQueryable<Customer> customers = null;
if (customers != null)
    customers.Concat(_context.Developers.Include(s => s.Project)
        .ThenInclude(op => op.Customer)
        .Where(developer=> developer.DeveloperId == userId).Select(developer => developer.Project.Customer));
else 
    customers = _context.Developers.Include(s => s.Project)
        .ThenInclude(op => op.Customer)
        .Where(developer=> developer.DeveloperId == userId).Select(developer => developer.Project.Customer));
```

I have already tried initializing customers as

```cs
customers = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

This results in another exception: *The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider.*

Comment: Are you looping on a list of userId values?

Comment: I have a Model of developer, is basically a middle table, which contains a list of Projects and a Developer Id. The Projects associated to this developer are those in which this Developer is assigned to work for.

Comment: I need to extract the Customer record which is further located inside a Project record

Comment: No, the userId is a singular string value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "save" the extra customers query in variable and use it:

```
var extraCustomersQuery = _context.Developers.Include(s => s.Project)
                            .ThenInclude(op => op.Customer)
                            .Where(developer=> developer.DeveloperId == userId).Select(developer => developer.Project.Customer));

customers = customers?.Concat(extraCustomersQuery) ?? extraCustomersQuery;
```

also if you are just looping on a set of user ids you can create just one query with `Contains` without `Concat`ing multiple ones (assuming `userIds` is a collection of user ids), also if you need only `Customer` the query should work fine without the includes:

```
var customers = _context.Developers
    .Where(developer => userIds.Contains(developer.DeveloperId))
    .Select(developer => developer.Project.Customer));
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you think that userId was a collection? Please suggest any improvements in the query as well, given that the userId is a single string

Comment: @RidaM was glad to help. I was not assuming that `userId` is a collection, I assumed that `userIds` is a collection, cause the whole structure looks like you are looping through one concatenating the queries. There are other possibilities obviously but without surrounding code it is hard to suggest anything.

Comment: `public class Developer
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Project Project{ get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string DeveloperId { get; set; }
        public string DeveloperName {get; set;}
}

public class Project 
{
      // among many other attributed
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }
      public Customer Customer { get; set; }
      public ICollection<Developer> Developers { get; set; }
}
`

Apologies for the formatting issues. 
Hope that the above class structure helps

Comment: @RidaM I was talking more about the code surrounding the one in question.

Comment: There is no other code surrounding this section of code. I have this code in a mediatR handler where it receives userId of a developer and I have to return list of customers associated with that developer

Comment: @RidaM why then you need `IQueryable<Customer> customers = null;`?

Comment: I yet have to add more if else conditions in which I will be accessing different tables but that is not yet a priority